# PageType Content Grouping on a Rollup property?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics account with several profiles, each with PageType content groups setup. I also have a rollup property containing all my data, but no page grouping.

Is it possible to setup a PageType content group on a rollup property in Google Analytics?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you will need to configure this content grouping (Admin > View > Content Grouping) separately for the rollup property.